# install4j: Installation doesnt create an alternativeLogfile

Tags: install4j

When i Invoke the installer with:

```
installerchecker_windows-x64_19_2_1_0-SNAPSHOT.exe 
-q 
-c 
-varfile install.varfile 
-Dinstall4j.alternativeLogfile=d:/tmp/logs/installchecker.log 
-Dinstall4j.logToStderr=true
```

it creates and writes the standard log file `installation.log` in the `.install4j` Directory, but doesnt create my custom log in `d:/tmp/logs`. As configured there is an additional error.log with the correct content. 
The installation.log shows the comand-line config : `install4j.alternativeLogfile=d:/tmp/logs/installchecker.log`
The Directory `d:/tmp/logs` has full access.
Where is the failure in my config ?

Answer (score 0):

The alternative log file is intended to debug situations where the installer fails. To avoid moving the log file to its final destination in `.install4j/installation.log`, the  VM parameter

```
-Dinstall4j.noPermanentLogFile=true
```

can be specified.